# XML file with other xml file references

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, spyder

I have an xml file with shapes and references to other xml files.
How can i call tell python to recognize these references of xml and load their information? To make a total drawing.
Read the xml file and if you see a reference of an xml file load that information also. That is what i want python (spyder) to be able to do.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 



mytree = ET.parse("C:/Users/f.badloe/OneDrive - BELLT/Documents/OnderhoudBediening/OnderhoudBediening/AfsluitdijkObjecten/Cilinder/Cilinder.pnl")
myroot = mytree.getroot()

#print(myroot.tag)
FileName = []
for prop in myroot.findall(".//shapes//reference//prop[@name= 'FileName']"):
    FileName.append(prop.text)
    FileName = ''.join(FileName).split()
    print(FileName[0])
    
# //prop[@name= 'FileName']
# [@Name= 'LENGTEMETING']

# =============================================================================
# for prop in myroot.findall(".//reference/"):
#     reference = print(prop.attrib)
#     print(reference)
# =============================================================================
```

[reference files in the original xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur7SF.png)

Comment: I am able to localize the xml references. Only problem now is pulling out the information

Comment: Code must be posted as text not an image. Besides, questions must provide a [mcve].

Comment: No xml available.